# Subtracting element of ith position from element at (i + 1)th position of any list in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a list of count values of some variable (tot-turtles) increasing with each tick. I tried the below code but all time list is having single element  of length 1. neither i is getting incremented. please correct me.

```
set tot-turtles count turtles 

to go
  let mylist [ ]
  set mylist lput tot-turtles mylist  ;    show mylist 

  set i 1
  foreach mylist [       ; print ?        ;show i
     set x ? - i         ; print x
     set i (i + 1)        ;show i
  ]
 end
```

I want to subtract elements of list in the following fashion where the length of list depends on the number of simulation run or till simulation ends, then
i need subtraction of element as element at (i + 1)th - element at ith position till the end of the list.

In the above code i is 1 then increments by 1 ie 2 and then continue to 1 2 1 2 1 2. mylsit always shows single element. Confused with "?" , it gives element of current position if i am not wrong, but how we know the current position?

Please help me out of these doubts and code. thanks a lot.

Thank you sir, yes i was doing mistake with local and global variable i checkd it later. and the thing i wanted is as below.

```
  to setup 
          set mylist [ 0] 
          set item-difference 0
  end  

  to go 
     set tot-turtles count tutles set 

     mylist lput tot-turtles mylist 
     let _n (length mylist) 
     set item-difference (( item ( _n - 1 ) mylist - item ( _n - 2 ) mylist )         
 end
```

I hope you got Allan sir.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to tell what you are after, but it seems you are using a local variable when you want a global variable.  See if this offers some help:

```
globals [mylist]

to setup
  ca
  set mylist []
  crt 10
end

to go
  crt 1
  set mylist lput (count turtles) mylist  ;    show mylist 
end

to test
  let _n (length mylist)
  (foreach mylist n-values _n [? + 1] [
    print ?1 - ?2
  ])
end
```